# Wrong HTML warning in PhpStorm

Tags: html, laravel, phpstorm

I need to use **[custom if statement](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#custom-if-statements)** in Laravel, but I don't know why PhpStorm says:

> tag start is not closed!

Here is my code:

```
<a href="#" @RouteNameCheck('home') class="white-color" @endRouteNameCheck></a>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: At first glance it looks like PhpStorm is not recognizing that custom tag at all. have you added it to the list of Blade tags in PhpStorm settings? (hint: open Settings/Preferences and type "blade" in search box for faster navigation). See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/blade.html . At the same time -- you may _possibly_ need to add a space between closing blade directive and `>` (as it _may_ treat it as one thing sometimes)

Comment: thanks, the problem solved by adding in the setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In PhpStorm, open Preferences, and navigate to Languages and Frameworks -> PHP -> Blade
2. Click on the Directives tab.
3. Add your new blade directives